# Load Soundcloud embedded player OnClick not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, onclick, soundcloud

Website: https://www.buybeatsfast.com/beats/

Clicking the "Play Beat" image should load the Soundcloud player for that track and autoplay it. This works in Chrome but in Firefox it just takes you to the Soundcloud track's page. I tested this on Windows XP and Windows 8 and it's just not working at all in Firefox, no errors on the console either so I have no clue what the problem is, I'm not the author of this code, I found it on here actually.

This is the html:

```
<div class="tempsc"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/rockitpro/imstillherehook" class="scload"><span class="playbeat"><span class="icon-play-sign playbeaticon"></span> Play Beat</span></a></div>
```

This is the js:

```
/*SOUNDCLOUD CLICK TO PLAY*/
var formatPlayer    = '&iframe=true';
formatPlayer   += '&color=3498DB';
formatPlayer   += '&buying=false';
formatPlayer   += '&download=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_playcount=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_reposts=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_user=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_comments=false';
formatPlayer   += '&liking=false';
formatPlayer   += '&hide_related=true';
formatPlayer   += '&sharing=false';
formatPlayer   += '&maxheight=125';
formatPlayer   += '&auto_play=true'; // Play once user clicks link!
formatPlayer   += '&show_artwork=true';
//LOAD IFRAME ON CLICK
$('.scload').click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
var $link = $(this);
var getJSONstring = 'https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&amp;url=' + $link.attr('href') + formatPlayer;
//Replace contents
$.getJSON(getJSONstring + '&amp;callback=?', function(response) {
var widget = response.html;
var src = $(widget).attr('src');
widget = $(widget).attr('src', src.replace('?visual=true', '?visual=false')); // Update iFrame src
$link.replaceWith(widget); }); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Forgot to pass in `event` into the `click` function. This now works in Firefox.

```
/*SOUNDCLOUD CLICK TO PLAY*/
var formatPlayer    = '&iframe=true';
formatPlayer   += '&color=3498DB';
formatPlayer   += '&buying=false';
formatPlayer   += '&download=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_playcount=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_reposts=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_user=false';
formatPlayer   += '&show_comments=false';
formatPlayer   += '&liking=false';
formatPlayer   += '&hide_related=true';
formatPlayer   += '&sharing=false';
formatPlayer   += '&maxheight=125';
formatPlayer   += '&auto_play=true'; // Play once user clicks link!
formatPlayer   += '&show_artwork=true';
//LOAD IFRAME ON CLICK
$('.scload').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $link = $(this);
var getJSONstring = 'https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&amp;url=' + $link.attr('href') + formatPlayer;
//Replace contents
$.getJSON(getJSONstring + '&amp;callback=?', function(response) {
var widget = response.html;
var src = $(widget).attr('src');
widget = $(widget).attr('src', src.replace('?visual=true', '?visual=false')); // Update iFrame src
$link.replaceWith(widget); }); });
```